# Consulta SQL con calculo de totales

Tags: sql, select, oracle-11g

Buen día, estoy intentando hacer una consulta SQL en Oracle 11g, quiero cacular el total de prendas que se tienen en la tabla de hechos, pero quiero mostrar todos los datos de la tabla más aparte adicionando un campo que diga total.

Hasta ahora tengo estos resultados, pero no se como se puedan mostrar todos los campos más la columna que les comentaba, espero me puedan ayudar de antemano.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]